# How to copy the return value of an interactive process from docker to WebSocket?

Tags: python, docker, go

I am writing data from web browser to an interactive process (python) on docker via WebSocket and Docker SDK.

Data: Web browser <-> Server <-> Docker (interactive process)

I want to get the output of python. For example. the input is `1 + 1`, then I want to get `2`.

The issue is I am getting the first line returned (line by line). In this example, it is

`�Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 20:35:49)`

`[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux`

```
import (
"fmt"
"github.com/gorilla/websocket"
"net/http")

var upgrader = websocket.Upgrader{}

func echo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
upgrader.CheckOrigin = func(r *http.Request) bool { return true }

conn, err := upgrader.Upgrade(w, r, nil) // error ignored for sake of simplicity
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

resp := StartRuntime([]string{"python"})

for {
    // Read message from browser
    msgType, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    resp.Conn.Write(msg)

    dockermsg, err := resp.Reader.ReadBytes(byte('\n')) <--I think I need to modify this line, but I am not sure how.
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Print(string(dockermsg))
    err = conn.WriteMessage(msgType, dockermsg)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
} 

func StartRuntime(cmd []string) types.HijackedResponse {
cli, ctx := getClient()

containerID := "9fba076ba45b0c29f8787ee0031ff12186a870461356e79da8fff8e3eaddc62d"

cli.ContainerStart(ctx, containerID, types.ContainerStartOptions{})

execID, _ := cli.ContainerExecCreate(ctx, containerID, types.ExecConfig{Cmd: cmd,
    AttachStdin:  true,
    AttachStdout: true,
    AttachStderr: true,
    Tty:          true})

resp := getResponse(execID.ID)

return resp
}

func getResponse(id string) types.HijackedResponse {
cli, ctx := getClient()

resp, err := cli.ContainerExecAttach(ctx, id, types.ExecStartCheck{})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
return resp
}
```

Comment: What is `StartRuntime()`?

Comment: It returns response from `cli.ContainerExecCreate` in Docker SDK. Should I paste the code here?

Comment: That may help, yes. Also please indicate which packages are you using (import path).

Comment: Now you also introduced a new function: `getResponse()`. Can you show us that too? (I'm mainly interested in what the type of `resp.Reader` will be.)

Comment: Added. Appreciated it. resp is of type `type HijackedResponse struct {
 Conn   net.Conn
 Reader *bufio.Reader
}` . I use this to read/write from/to the python process on docker.

Comment: @icza Are there any other information I need to add?

Comment: `bufio.Reader.ReadBytes('\n')` reads only a single line. If your python app outputs multiple lines, you have to keep reading multiple lines, and discard the ones you're not interested in.